Difficulty Changing YouTube Video Quality in Flutter Windows Application Using webview_windows
In my Flutter application for Windows, I'm utilizing webview_windows to handle HTML for playing YouTube videos. Here's a snippet of my code:
import 'package:webview_windows/webview_windows.dart';

final _controller = WebviewController();


await _controller.initialize();
final result = await _controller.executeScript(
          'window.dispatchEvent(new Event("flutterContextMenu", { bubbles: false, cancelable: false, data: "disable" }));');

await _controller.setBackgroundColor(Colors.transparent);

// await _controller.setPopupWindowPolicy(WebviewPopupWindowPolicy.deny);

await _controller.loadStringContent(data); // here the data is youtube video player html data

The issue I'm encountering is that the options for changing video quality and other settings are not clickable when using mouse click interactions. However, using the keyboard shortcuts such as "Tab", "Enter", and "Arrow keys" works fine and allows me to open the quality change popup and adjust the quality accordingly.
It's worth mentioning that this functionality works flawlessly on mobile devices with inAppWebview, but due to limited options, I opted for webview_windows for Windows support.
Question:
How can I enable the ability to change video quality in my Flutter Windows application using mouse click interactions, similar to how it functions with keyboard shortcuts?
